# Whenever I try any command using go, the output says that my go-build is corrupted and unreadable

Tags: go, build, command, temp, corrupted-state-exception

Whenever I run any go command at all (other than `go help`) the output is this:

```
mkdir C:\Users\LUCAS_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build268335003: The file or 
directory is corrupted and unreadable.
```

I'm not sure why this is happening, I've tried restarting, and that temporarily fixes it, but then after a couple of commands are executed, this starts happening again. I'm not sure if this will help, but my username is not `LUCAS_~1` it's `Lucas_000`. Also, I've checked my `Temp` folder, and there doesn't seem to be anything named "go-build268335003".

Any help would be  appreciated, thanks!

Comment: truncating and appending `~1`, `~2`, etc was how late versions of DOS truncated long file names from Windows 9x, but that shouldn't be happening here. What is the value of `%TEMP%`?

Comment: Well I have Windows 8, if that helps at all

Comment: Can you try `echo %TEMP%` (or `echo $Env:TEMP` in powershell)? It could be something screwed up the value of your `TEMP` environment variable.

Comment: `echo %TEMP%` outputs `C:\Users\LUCAS_~1\AppData\Local\Temp`


`echo $Env:TEMP` outputs `$Env:TEMP`

Comment: Well, there is your problem. Reset `TEMP` to the real path, and it should work.

Comment: Even after resetting `TEMP`, `echo %TEMP%` outputs:

`C:\Users\LUCAS_~1\AppData\Local\Temp`


I changed `TEMP` in the Environment variables and I used: 

`setx TEMP C:\Users\LUCAS_000\AppData\Local\Temp`

And so when I try `go version`, again it outputs:

`mkdir C:\Users\LUCAS_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build407496999: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.`

Comment: You may need to restart your computer, at a minimum you need to restart your command interpreter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163606/discussion-between-lucas-a-and-milo-christiansen).

Answer (score 0):

My first guess (confirmed in the comments) is that the `TEMP` environment variable is set to a DOS 8.3 path, truncating the user name using the DOS rules. How this came to be, I have no idea.

Fixing the problem is simple: Change `TEMP` to the full path.

The easy way is to open a command prompt and run the following:

```
setx TEMP C:\Users\LUCAS_000\AppData\Local\Temp
```

The slightly harder (but clearer) way (for Windows 8) is to follow the following sequence:

```
Start -> All Apps -> Control panel -> System ->
Advanced System Settings -> Advanced -> Environment variables
```

Comment: Even after resetting `TEMP`, `echo %TEMP%` outputs:

`C:\Users\LUCAS_~1\AppData\Local\Temp`


I changed `TEMP` in the Environment variables and I used: 

`setx TEMP C:\Users\LUCAS_000\AppData\Local\Temp`

And so when I try `go version`, again it outputs:

`mkdir C:\Users\LUCAS_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build407496999: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.`